# slim framework render if url add '/' then doesn't load CSS

Tags: php, frameworks, slim

I'm a PHP beginner and new on slim framework.

Here is my motivation after watching "PHP Slim Framework Simple Demo"(http://youtu.be/26CRc89gN10).

I've followed the film and also succeed, but there is a bug and I don't know how to fix it.

Below are my code:

---

```
// helloslim.php
<?
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/hello/:name', function ($name) {
/*render through some template page*/
});
$app->run();
?>
```

---

- It works well when I use

> localhost/dir/helloslim.php/hello/yoyo

- but it doesn't load css when I use

> localhost/dir/helloslim.php/hello/yoyo/

I don't know why? Can someone tell me?

Comment: Your urls seem equal or am I shortsighted?

Comment: There is more "/" in the end on the second url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not Slim related but basic HTML.  Your css tag is something like following.

```
 <link media=screen href="css/styles.css" rel=stylesheet />
```

If the url you access is `http://example.com/foo` then style sheet will be accessed from `http://example.com/css/styles.css`. However if the url is `http://example.com/foo/` then css will be accessed from `http://example.com/foo/css/styles.css`.

Use absolute path in stylesheet tag.

```
 <link media=screen href="/css/styles.css" rel=stylesheet />
```

Now in both cases css will be accessed from `http://example.com/css/styles.css`.

Comment: btw,in XAMPP,I need to use href="./css/style.css"